# Spring-Boot, how to start it manually in a servlet 3.0 environment

Tags: spring-boot

I have following problem. I have a spring boot configuration in a servlet 2.5 container which has a manual startup within a specialized security context/ privileged action context. So starting from what spring-boot-legacy provides I have implemented my own ContextLoaderListener and wired it into the web.xml:

```
public class SecurityContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

@Override
  public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

     SecurityContextAction action =  new SecurityContextAction() {
       public Object run() throws Exception {

         initSpringBoot(servletContextEvent);
         return null;
     }
  };
  SecurityContextHelper.runAction(action);
```

So there is a special non spring security context which is enforced by the underlying environment I have to deploy against. The initSpringBoot is basically the same as spring-boot-legacy provides.

```
public WebApplicationContext initSpringBoot(final ServletContext servletContext) {
    String configLocationParam = servletContext.getInitParameter("contextConfigLocation");
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder((Object[]) StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(configLocationParam, ",; \t\n"));
    Class contextClass = this.determineContextClass(servletContext);
    builder.contextClass(contextClass);
    builder.initializers(new ApplicationContextInitializer[]{new ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericWebApplicationContext>() {
        public void initialize(GenericWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            applicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
        }
    }});
    WebApplicationContext context = (WebApplicationContext)builder.run(new String[0]);
    servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, context);
    return context;
}
```

Now my problem is I have to move in the long run to a Servlet 3.0 environment where spring boot automatically initialized, hence I am prevented to start spring and with it Spring boot manually in my own security context. Is there a way to disable the auto startup of spring/spring-boot in a servlet 3.0 environment so that I still can start the entire spring environment within my own security context? I cannot find any starting point in the sources where the spring initialization and spring boot initialization is triggered by the annotation scanning mechanisms of a servlet 3.0 container.

Comment: Why would you need to extend the `ContextLoaderListener` for that? A plain `ServletContextListener` would be as effective as you are overriding the whole behavior of the `ContextLoaderListener`. For Spring Boot find the `SpringBootServletInitializer`, extend it, override the `onStartup` method and do there what you are now doing in the `contextInitialized` method. Should work equally wel I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

For a Spring Boot application to start automatically in a Servlet 3.0 container, you need to add a `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass to your application.

> Is there a way to disable the auto startup of spring/spring-boot in a servlet 3.0 environment

Yes, don't add a `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass to your application.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the fast answer,  I will give it a shot, but I am not sure if this will work because as far as I can see spring still is autostarted for the scan for SpringBootServletInitializer. I want to disable even the spring autostart and start it on my own.

Comment: Ok just to answer my own question, I probably have to turn off the SpringServletContainerInitializer one way or the other. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a last answer to this.

To turn of the spring-web autoconfiguration, you definitely have to remove the SpringServletContainerInitializer and its associated config file from spring web. 
There does not seem to be any other way.

Spring should move all autoconfig mechanisms into a separate module, so that it does not enforce its autoconfigs on everyone. There always will be corner cases which won't work (like mine which enforces a security context during container bootstrapping time).

Either way. I used the Maven shade plugin to remove ServletContextInitializers and the service file which points to the initializer. And then I used either spring-boot-legacy or my own startup code derived from legacy to bootstrap spring in my own security context.

here is the shade plugin entry:

```
   <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>org.springframework:spring-web</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

The trick is then to exclude the spring-web from spring-boot-web and add your own shaded dependency instead. That way you will get rid of the pesky autostartup of spring-web.
For bootstrapping the simplest way is to use spring-boot-legacy this also works for servlet 3.0 systems.